# Navigate to tab on Button click

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two tabs below [Search and Result]

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs adv-src-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let isFirst = first" [class.active]="isFirst" role="presentation">
            <a href="#{{tab}}" (click)="setSelectTab(tab)" aria-controls="profile" data-toggle="tab">{{tab}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

On Search button click, I need to active the Result tab.

I am using Typescript and Angular 2.0.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what you did in this function `setSelectTab`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `navigateByUrl`  From `Router`

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';


export class myComponent{

setSelectTab(tab){
this.parentRouter = Router;
this.parentRouter.navigateByUrl('/'+tab);
}
}
```